# Optimizing flink windowing

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have flink job where I need to dedupe the received records in 1 hour window. Once deduped, I need to gather all these documents that are deduped and do some aggregation like counting and then produce to destination topic.

Attached is the picture of my flink job:[image: Attached is the picture of my flink job]

Now, as I just need to gather those deduped documents, i may not necessarily need to wait for 1 hour. How can I avoid this windowing of 1 hour just to gather those documents but as soon as they gathered just proceed further with aggregation.

Due to this the resources hold on to memory and checkpointing size is increasing which I want to avoid.

Watermark strategy:

```
WatermarkStrategy<PlImaGuidInterimMessageVO> watermarkStrategy =  WatermarkStrategy
            .<PlImaGuidInterimMessageVO>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofMillis(maxOutOfOrderness))
            .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.getEventTimeStamp());
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: With event time windows, you shouldn't have to wait. How is your timestamp assigner and watermark generator configured?

Comment: Updated the description with watermark strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are doing something unusual that isn't shown, the second layer of windows will close as soon as they receive the results of the first layer. In other words, as soon as the deduplication is done, you should have the final results.

However, tumbling windows aren't an ideal technique for implementing deduplication. The issue is that the windows are aligned to the epoch. This means that an event with a timestamp of 1:59, with a duplicate at 2:01, will not be deduplicated.

In my opinion, you'd do better to use a simple KeyedProcessFunction with a timer. Key the stream so that only duplicates have the same key, and use a Boolean in ValueState to remember if a given key has been seen recently enough that subsequent appearances should be filtered out. Use a Timer to clear the state.

Session windows are another good way to implement deduplication, though the semantics are again different.